# How to set margin for elements in my case

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a response view for my app.

Currently I have two column

The left one should be flexible depending on the browser width and the right one has set width of 120px.

html

```
<div class="wrapper row">
    <div class="left col-xs-9">
        This is the left column
    </div>
     <div class="right col-xs-3">
         Right column
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
.left {
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

The problem is I need to have 20px margin between these two columns no matter what browser width is while the right one maintain 120px width. How do I do this? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ufk1xxc/2/

Comment: Is it not already doing what you want?

Comment: no if you narrow the browser width, the right column will be pushed to second line

Comment: What about the following? http://jsfiddle.net/4ufk1xxc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the wrapper to a flexbox solves the problem:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t35oLLe7/)